# Google Maps API not loading on button click in chained function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Basically, I have a Google Maps API being loaded as a chained called from one function to another. I can make it work perfectly as demonstrated in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NateH06/2v55jcxo/1/), but for some reason, it won't load the actual Map into the targeted `div` when it's from a chained call with a little extra HTML. Here is the JsFiddle that is NOT working, but more closely represents my production code: https://jsfiddle.net/NateH06/twk9mtjg/2/ . The console printout indicates all the map bindings have successfully occurred, but it won't display in the targeted `div.gmap`.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div style="display: none;" class="googleMapsContainer" id="gm2">
  This Text Should be visible after click
  <div class="gmap" id="map">
    <!--Map should load here on button click -->
  </div>

</div>

<br>

<div class="tableProcessingToolBarContainer">
  <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="appSliderContent tptSliderContent container-fluid ">
        <button class="gmapInit glassyButton">View data in Google Maps</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYpu-wE1AEWVUzEUq7RXOhX_3dQUJ2RUw">
</script>
```

And here's the Javascript which all fires just fine:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gmapInit', function() {
  var mapContainer = $(this).parents("div.tableProcessingToolBarContainer").prevAll("div.googleMapsContainer:first");
  mapContainer.attr("style", "");
  var mapTarget = mapContainer.children(".gmap");
  initMap(mapTarget);
});

function initMap(targetElem) {
  console.log("this fires, here's target elem: ");
  console.log(targetElem);
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(targetElem, {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  console.log(map);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
  console.log(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in jsfiddle your the line

```
 console.log(targetElem);
```

shows up as

```
 [div#map.gmap]
```

in the console?

That's because your targetElem variable is actually collection of elements, which is what jQuery selectors return (a jQuery object).  The google.maps.Map constructor takes a single element in the constructor.  So you could do targetElem[0] to get the first element in the collection which is what you actually want in this case.  However, I would recommend restructuring how you're selecting that element because it's a little bit hard to follow the chain of selectors.  Is there any reason you couldn't just do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gmapInit', function() {
     var mapTarget = document.getElementById("map");
     initMap(mapTarget);
});
```

Comment: Holy cow, that's all it was?! Dang. I have to have a further chain of selectors because there may be multiple `googleMapsContainers` on the same page at any given time, and I need to get specific with which one I'm selecting. That's it though, thanks!